# Redux fetch not going through

Tags: reactjs, redux, fetch

I'm trying to add Redux to my test app but I'm having trouble fetching data from my API. It feels like I've gone through all of the steps but I can't access the props from the fetch in my component, so I'm messing up somewhere along the way. My code:

actions/index.js:

```
import 'whatwg-fetch';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';

export const FETCH_RECIPES = 'FETCH_RECIPES';
const ROOT_URL = 'http://myapi/recipe/';

export function fetchRecipes(id) {
    const url = ROOT_URL + "0";
    // const request = fetch(url);
    return (dispatch) => {
    fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((request) => dispatch(fetchRecipesSuccess(request)))
    };
}

export function fetchRecipesSuccess(request) {
    return {
        type: FETCH_RECIPES,
        request
    };
}
```

reducer_recipe.js:

```
import { FETCH_RECIPES } from "../actions/index";

export default function(state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_RECIPES:
            return [action.payload.data, ...state];
    }

    return state;
}
```

reducers/index.js:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import RecipesReducer from './reducer_recipes';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    recipes: RecipesReducer
})

export default rootReducer;
```

aaaaand in my component I'm using this code:

```
function mapStateToProps({ recipes }) {
    return { recipes };
}

connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchRecipes})(Recipe);
```

And in my index.js I'm creating my store with `const createStoreWithMiddleware = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise));`

With my thinking I should be good to use this.props to access the data I've fetched from my API but I guess I'm dropping the data somewhere along the way. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, check your reducer well. You should be returning `action.request.data`. And you can console.log the action object to see what you've got

Answer (score 1):

Check your reducer well. You seem to be returning `action.payload.data` whereas in your `fetchRecipesSuccess`, it's named `request`. And you can console.log the action object to see what you've got

```
import { FETCH_RECIPES } from "../actions/index";

export default function(state = [], action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case FETCH_RECIPES:
        // Verify here that your request object has data
        return [...state, action.request.data];
       // Default state
    default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! That's a big miss on my part. Although, when I console.log(action.request.data) nothing happens -- it's as if the reducer isn't running in my application. Do I have to wire it up in some way?

Comment: Can you verify that you imported your reducers as `reducers` the way it's here =>  `const createStoreWithMiddleware = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise));`

Comment: Yes, that is how my code looks, and I'm wrapping my <App /> with a `<Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware}>`.

Comment: I changed to `applyMiddleware(thunk)` as that's what I've been trying to use, but still it doesn't work. In the reducer, it goes into the default case, instead of `case FETCH_RECIPES`... I'm lost!

Comment: Just wait, I'm testing out something on that. And if you can use codesandbox.io to share it that would be fine. Just replace your api call with a mock data.

Comment: I updated the answer because I don't know if you're using `object-spread` operator plugin which could be overwriting your data with the initial value. That said, ensure you're getting your data in the reducer and your answer is with you

Comment: I'm also wondering what you're doing with `id` in your thunk `fetchRecipes(id)`